# Split methods on XPath 1.0

Tags: xpath

I use 'XPath', how  I can simulate split method?

I read documentation and I know that XPath version 1.0 not have this method.

I have document contains this tags:

```
<TestCategoryModule>
   <ItemCategories>
      <![CDATA[Birthday Travel,Travel]]>
   </ItemCategories>
</TestCategoryModule>

<TestCategoryModule2>
   <ItemCategories>
      <![CDATA[Travel]]>
   </ItemCategories>
</TestCategoryModule2>
```

I want filter item by 'ItemCategories', but when I filtered by world 'Travel',  return 2 item. I use this filter "ItemCategories[contains(text(), 'Travel')]".

I want that I filter by "Travel" return only second item. How can do it?

Comment: What is the general rule that you want to apply? You've given one example, but one example doesn't make a specification. Why do you think a split() method is needed?

Comment: @MichaelKay, I believe he wants to splint on a space ...

Comment: If you're right, then it's a remarkable piece of guesswork!

Comment: @MichaelKay Yes, it is remarkable guessing, and no, I was not right :) But this was a step forward to make the OP explain it better (in a separate answer ! ) so now it is clear -- this is a CSV and he wants only to select only elements whose string value contains the item "Travel"

Comment: My items have categories and I want to add a filter by category. But if there is a category "Travel" and a category "Birthday Travel" then the contains method will display items that have the first or second category. Because the second category contains the word "Travel", but the second is not a category  "Travel".

Comment: @DenisLogachov, Are there any reasons for not accepting an answer?

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
/*/*/*[contains(concat(',', ., ','), ',Travel,')]
```

**Here is XSLT-based verification**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:copy-of select=
     "/*/*/*[contains(concat(',', ., ','), ',Travel,')]"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**When this transformation is applied on this XML document** (essentially the provided XML fragment, extended with one more test case and made a well-formed XML document:

```
<t>
    <TestCategoryModule>
        <ItemCategories>Birthday Travel,Travel</ItemCategories>
    </TestCategoryModule>
    <TestCategoryModule2>
        <ItemCategories>Birthday Travel</ItemCategories>
    </TestCategoryModule2>
    <TestCategoryModule2>
        <ItemCategories>Travel</ItemCategories>
    </TestCategoryModule2>
</t>
```

**The wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<ItemCategories>Birthday Travel,Travel</ItemCategories>
<ItemCategories>Travel</ItemCategories>
```

Comment: You really help in this one, Dimitre!

Comment: Thanks @Alejandro -- There is a general principle of removing the need to deal with edge cases (boundary conditions).  "**Sentinel Programming**": https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sentinel_value

Answer (score 0):

You actually don't need `split()` for the problem that you've described. If you want to match `Travel` but not `Travel,Travel` you want `=` instead of `contains()`. To deal with the whitespace around your CDATA sections, wrap it in `normalize-space()`.

All put together, try `ItemCategories[normalize-space(text()) = 'Travel']`.

Comment: There is no "==" operator in XPath. I think you probably meant "=". But I have no idea if you have understood the question correctly (I haven't understood it all...)

Answer (score 0):

I was a little wrong, or poorly described problumu. The problem is that the categories are stored as a string. I have three items, the first one contains categories: (Birthday Travel,Travel), second: (Birthday Travel), third: (Travel). When I request filtering for the word "Travel", I need to get the first and third items, but I get all three items, because all items contain world "Travel".

Comment: Please use the *Post answer* button only for actual answers. You should modify your original question to add additional information.